# Add line breaks after n numbers of letters in long words

Tags: javascript, jquery

A have a string that can reach up to 100 characters in lenght. Is there an easy way to insert line breaks in the word every 10th letter? For example:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Should turn in to

```
aaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaa
```

I know that i can modify html with the html() method, but im not sure how to count characters and insert the tags. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
string.match(/.{1,10}/g).join("<br/>");
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EZEQu/5/ just to make it easy for @vision bruv :)) :P working innit

Comment: @VisioN my mistake - I was testing with `.join()` and forgot the implicit comma

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text is inside a div or a span:

```
<div id="myDiv">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

You can do:

```
$(function() {
    var html=$('#myDiv').html();
    var newHtml='';
    for (var i=0;i<html.length;i++) {
        newHtml=newHtml+html[i];
        if ((i+1)%10==0) {newHtml=newHtml+'<br/>';}
    }
    $('#myDiv').html(newHtml);
});
```

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/68PvB/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your string in a variable you can use its `replace` method like this:

```
var chunklen = 2;      //the length of the chunks you require
var str = '123456789'; //your string
var rxp = new RegExp( '(.{'+chunklen+'})', 'g' );

var str2 = str.replace( rxp, '$1<br/>' );

console.log( str2 );   //12<br/>34<br/>56<br/>78<br/>9
```