# write vertically in table rows

Tags: html, css

I want to write vertically in HTML table.In the last column, I want to the text "time table" to be displayed vertically. It should cover all the rows. Something like this:

L

U

N

C

H

How to do this ?
Here is the table i want to create.

```
<table style = "border-collapse: collapse"  border = "1px">

  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="6" align="center"> Time Table </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
       <th>DAY/TIME</th>
       <th>8-9</th>
       <th>9-10</th>
       <th>10-11</th>
       <th>11-12</th>
      <th rowspan = "6" style="verticle-align: buttom">Lunch Break</th>
     </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>


  </thead> 

</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your lunch break text inside a div and apply this css

```
word-wrap: break-word;width:11px;
```

Have a look at this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ8GJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an id (or class) to the th you want vertical text in, and then you can add the following jQuery function - adds a line break after each character:

```
$(function() {
    var html=$('#verticalText').html();
    var newHtml='';
    for (var i=0;i<html.length;i++) {
        newHtml=newHtml+html[i];
        newHtml=newHtml+'<br/>';
    }
    $('#verticalText').html(newHtml);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3Ab2/

(modified from Naor's answer to: [Add line breaks after n numbers of letters in long words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798734/add-line-breaks-after-n-numbers-of-letters-in-long-words))

Answer (score 0):

Use following HTML code

```
<table id="MyTable" style = "border-collapse: collapse"  border = "1px">
```

Time Table

```
<tr>
   <th>DAY/TIME</th>
   <th>8-9</th>
   <th>9-10</th>
   <th>10-11</th>
   <th>11-12</th>
  <th rowspan = "6" id="vertical" style="verticle-align: buttom">Lunch Break</th>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <th>Mon</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Tue</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Wed</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Thu</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Fri</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Use Following CSS

```
table#MyTable tr th#vertical {
    width: 1.2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #000;
    /*Firefox*/
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /*Safari*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /*Opera*/
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /*IE*/
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    filter: flipv fliph;
    border:1px black solid;
}
```

[See this link](http://jsfiddle.net/8zWWk/)