# Insert a Break after every 55 characters

Tags: php, jquery

I want to insert a **line Break** after every **55** characters i have made a `jquery` script but it doesn't work can some one please point me in the right direction

Jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text_comment').text($(this).val().replace(/([\s\S]{55})/g, '$1<br />'));

});
```

Index.php

```
<input type="text" class="comment" id="text_comment"autocomplete="off"time_date="<?php echo $date_shared;?>" 
    username="<?php echo $comment_username;?>"post_id="<?php echo $shared_id2; ?>"placeholder="Write a Comment"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add line breaks after n numbers of letters in long words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798734/add-line-breaks-after-n-numbers-of-letters-in-long-words)

Comment: why dont use textarea and \n to break ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery or javascript to add one line break <br /> after x amount of characters in a <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068653/jquery-or-javascript-to-add-one-line-break-br-after-x-amount-of-characters-i)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: none of them seem to work it just keeps going on and on instead of goin on a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line-breaks are [automatically removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) from `inputs` with a type of `text`.

> text: A single-line text field; line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.

You can use a `textarea` to display the line breaks:

```js
var myString = '1234567890';
myString = myString.replace(/.{1,2}/g, "$&\n"); //replace 2 with 55 for your example

document.getElementById('text').value = myString; // :(
document.getElementById('textarea').value = myString; // :)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"> <-- line-breaks automatically removed
<br>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Comment: how would i implement this with the `id = text_comment`

Comment: I see - you want line-breaks inside of a `input type="text"` - for that HTML element, line-breaks are removed. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach.

```
$original = "Sample String.";
$parts = str_split($original, 4); //Replace '4' with '55' afterwards.
$final = implode("<br />", $parts);
```