# Can it possible to display the <a> tag text in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one  tag where the text in to that  tag will come dynamically from database. Now can it possible to display the  tag text in multiple lines? Ex: I want to display only 10 characters per line. If the dynamic text contain 29 characters then it should display in three lines, If the dynamic text contain only 9 characters then it should display in a single line.

Ex:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Welcome to w3schools site</a>
```

For the above code I need output like,

```
Welcome to
 w3schools
 site
```

Any suggestions to display output as shown above?

Comment: That is dynamic text don't know what text will come into that tag.

Comment: Use css `min-width` and `min-height`

Comment: Updated Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/hr6hq7uj/1/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ;
var htmlfoo = str.match(/.{1,10}/g).join("<br/>");

$('div').html(htmlfoo);
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZEQu/5/)

OR

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798734/add-line-breaks-after-n-numbers-of-letters-in-long-words)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to make array from your string and  `forEach()` to insert `<br>` after every 10th element

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a');
var str = a.innerHTML.split('');
str.forEach((e, i) => {
  if(i % 11 == 0 && i != 0) str.splice(i, 0, "<br>");
})

a.innerHTML = str.join('');
```

```html
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Welcome to w3schools site</a>
```

Comment: Do I need to place that script in document.ready()? Will this solution support in for loop also?

Answer (score 1):

You can approximimate this with the width value in `ch`

One 'ch` approximates with the width of 0 character glyph so the text space is proportional to the font size.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.ch10 {
  display: block;
  width: 10ch;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<a class="ch10" href="http://www.w3schools.com">Welcome to w3schools site</a>

<h1><a class="ch10" href="http://www.w3schools.com">0123456789</a></h1>


<a class="ch10" href="http://www.w3schools.com">012345678910</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` to get every word in text content. Then check if length of word less than 10 insert it into `a` and if length of word is great than 10 insert `<br/>` into `a`.

```js
var aElement = document.querySelector('a');
var words = aElement.innerHTML.split(" ");

var newText = "";
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    var textLength = newText.length + words[i].length;
    if (textLength > 10)
        newText += "<br/>";
    
    newText += " " + words[i];
}

aElement.innerHTML = newText;
```

```html
<a href="#">Welcome to w3schools site</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty but this is how I did it :

**HTML**

```
<a id="test" href="#">some text that is quite long</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var longtext = $('a#test').text();
  var chars = longtext.split("");
  var newtext = "";
  var charcount = 0;
  if (chars.length > 9)
  {


    for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {

         if (charcount > 9)
         {
              newtext += " <br> ";
              charcount = 0;
         }
         newtext += chars[i];
         ++charcount;
    }
    $('a#test').html(newtext);
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ng6ey9zL/

Comment: Your code break words when it length is grate than 10. See https://jsfiddle.net/ng6ey9zL/1/

Comment: @Mohammad yes it breaks by char not by word, but what if a word is longer than 10chars? I just applied the original requirements of OP, nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

First count the characters, then add `<br />` tag at end of 10 characters.